Appindicators are duplicated on initial boot, or when disabling / enabling Ubuntu Dock
I've noticed since upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, my appindicator icons are being duplicated.
This seems to be related to the Ubuntu Dock restarting or initialising.
Here are some screenshots showing the issue, and how I'm able to replicate it using the gnome-shell-extension-manager.
First boot:

Disable appindicators:

Enable appindicators:

Disable Ubuntu Dock:

Enable Ubuntu Dock:

It's a fairly minor bug, but it's annoying to deal with on every boot. Is anyone else seeing this on their installs?
